# ImageMagick is not processing png images

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

Could somebody know why this code below is working for **jpg** and **jpeg**, but not for **png**?

```
//Working as expected
exec($homePath.'/ImageMagick/bin/magick mogrify -scale 250x 
     -crop 160x160+'.$x.'+'.$y.' test.jpg');

//Not Working at all (png image is not processed)
exec($homePath.'/ImageMagick/bin/magick mogrify -scale 250x 
     -crop 160x160+'.$x.'+'.$y.' test.png');
```

I would appreciate if somebody could help. Thanks.

Here is the link of one of this png images:
http://www.freepngimg.com/download/space/9-2-space-picture.png

Comment: It works fine for me. Which errors you get? Can you share your PNG file?

Comment: Add `+repage` for png images. `exec($homePath.'/ImageMagick/bin/magick mogrify -scale 250x -crop 160x160+'.$x.'+'.$y.' +repage test.png');`

Comment: @bukkojot I added the image. But it is as if stackoverflow is converting it to jpg before posting here.

Comment: @Zindarod It is still not working with **+repage**

Comment: @stfsngue, you posted JPEG image.

Comment: @bukkojot it is as if stackoverflow is converting it to jpg before posting. I have added the link of this image.

Comment: Works fine for me, I get nice thumb with 160x131 pixel size. Try to launch it from terminal, you see any errors?

Comment: @bukkojot I installed a clean version in a my pc and tried it from terminal and it s working fine. What i ve installed in a hosting server  is the one who is not working, and i think it could be the version. I will try to install another version. Thanks for your help.